# Monotonicity of quantile function divided by its derivative and argument

Tags: probability, derivatives, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

Let $F$ be a CDF with $f\equiv F'$ **having a positive support** (edit), i.e. $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}_+$. Then $Q\equiv F^{-1}$ is its quantile function and $q\equiv Q'$, where we know $q(p) = \frac{1}{f(Q(p))}$. I am trying to prove under which conditions (if any) $$ \frac{d}{d p } \frac{Q(p)}{pq(p)}<0, \quad \forall p \in(0,1).$$

I cannot find any CDF $F$ (under the positive support assumption) for which this result does not hold (I tried both log-concave and log-convex distributions, with different signs of skewness). However I am unable to prove it holds generally. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would it hold for the standard normal distribution? If in Mathematica I set `F` to it, write `Q=InverseFunction[F][p];q=D[Q,p];D[Q/(p q),p]` and plot the result, the line intersects zero.

Comment: Great point, I forgot to specify that the support of $f$ is positive!